# Make Excel recognize Date format sent from PHP

Tags: php, excel

simple question here, I'm using PHPExcel to export a datagrid to an Excel file. In my datagrid, I have a few columns that contain dates and are formatted as 'Y-m-d'. When I extract the grid data, Excel does not recognize the data into those columns as Dates (Excel says that they have a General format and that they have no specific number format).

Is there anyway that I can format the dates so that Excel can recognize them as dates before the data is sent to Excel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel have in-built package to set number data as an excel date. 
If you i got you right then you are just passing number value as an date and getting type error.

Try like: `$date = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($data, "d-M-Y");`

Or refer doc link for more details: http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Style/PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html#constFORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#setting-a-date-andor-time-value-in-a-cell) and in the [Examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples) such as [02types.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/02types.php)

You need to convert those "formatted" dates to an MS Excel serialized date/timestamp

```
$dateString = '2015-12-21';
$excelTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($dateString);
```

and then set that $excelTimestamp as the cell value

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C9', $excelTimestamp);
```

You should then set the format mask for the cell

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('C9')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
```

Comment: it should be `$dateString = new DateTime('2015-12-21');` (with version 1.8.1 at least)

Comment: The `PHPToExcel()` method will accept either a unix timestamp, a recognisable string format (that would be recognised by DateTime), or a DateTime object

Comment: I see now, it was added with version 1.8.2. Thank you so much for your work Mark